# How to get openni working with unity5

Tags: kinect, openni, nite

I've downloaded unity5 and I'm trying to get a working example taking skeletal data from a Kinect camera an applying it to a puppet in unity. I've tried multiple approaches. I've tried **Kinect with OpenNI 1.5** that is available in the asset store as well as Zigfu. I cant seem to get any examples to work. I have openni, Nite and SensorKinect installed and working, but I can seem to get them working with Unity. Does anyone know wat I'm doing wrong or how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work in unity 5, I ended up having to re-download unity 4.5 and use a legacy version of zigfu

http://zigfu.com/en/downloads/legacy/